# Consumir dado JSON em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso de uma ajuda com javascript. Estou tentando mostrar na minha index.html os dados que estou consumindo de um json. Porém ao abrir a index e esperar o documento ser carregado os itens vem com undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var products = "";
    var url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/10p600";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,    
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if(response[0].erro) {
                $("h2").html(response[0].erro);
            }else {
                for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    products += "<div>";
                    products += "<div>" + response[i].imageName + "</div>";
                    products += "<h4>" + response[i].name + "</h4>";
                    products += "<p>" + response[i].price + "</p>";
                    products += "<p>" + response[i].paymentConditions + "</p>";    
                    products += "</div>";               
                }
                
                $("#myproducts").html(products);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Teste Front-End</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myproducts"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando for assim lembre-se de postar o JSON de origem, as perguntas não devem depender de links externos. Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].

Answer (score 2):

Você está acessando chaves que não existem no JSON, por isso que você recebe undefined.

A estrutura do JSON é:

```
[
    data: {
        item: {...},
        recommendation: [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...],
        widget: {
            size: 10
        }
    }
]
```

O que você quer acessar no seu código é `response[i].data.item.imageName`, `response[i].data.item.name`, `response[i].data.item.price` e `response[i].data.item.productInfo.paymentConditions`

**edit**

Ou caso você esteja tentando acessar as recomendações seria `response[0].data.recommendation[i].imageName`, `response[0].data.recommendation[i].name`, etc

Comment: Mas eu quero acessar os dados dos recommendation, para mostrar todos na index

Comment: Tente assim: response[0]['data'].item['imageName']

Comment: E para o recomendation: response[0]['data']['recommendation']

Comment: Sim fiz a mudança aqui, mas agora só aparece o primeiro dos recommendation, como faço para mostrar todos ?

Comment: Declare o for como `for(var i = 0; i < response[0].data.recommendation.length; i++)`

Comment: estou com problema ao renderizar a imagem dos produtos, estou chamado assim no js

Comment: products += "<img" + response[0].data.recommendation[i].imageName + ">";

Comment: @AlbertoMasculinoBorguesani na verdade, você está a adicionar o endereço, como se fosse um atributo do elemento `<img>`. Mas, para colocar o endereço da imagem, você precisa fazê-lo no atributo `src`. Portanto, ao invés de concatenar as strings, você poderia fazer assim: `\`<img src="${response[0].data.recommendation[i].imageName}" />\``.